# Integration of Socket.IO with VUE Framework

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

Hello I am trying to implement socket.io with vue.js however I cannot access the emits in the different views.

After configuring main.js I can get emits on the APP, but I can't get them on HOME.

Is it possible to help with this situation.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";

import * as io from "socket.io-client";
import VueSocketIO from "vue-socket.io";

Vue.use(
  new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: io("http://localhost:3001"),
  })
);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Here I have the implementation of the first view, and here I have access to the socket.io emit!

```html
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar app color="white" flat>
      <v-container class="py-0 fill-height">
        <v-avatar class="mr-10" color="grey darken-1" size="32"></v-avatar>

        <v-btn v-for="link in links" :key="link" text>
          {{ link }}
        </v-btn>

        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-responsive max-width="260">
          <v-switch
            v-model="switchLogIn"
            label="login"
            color="success"
            hide-details
          ></v-switch>
        </v-responsive>
      </v-container>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main class="grey lighten-3">
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet rounded="lg">
              <v-list color="transparent">
                <v-list-item v-for="n in 5" :key="n" link>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title> List Item {{ n }} </v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>

                <v-divider class="my-2"></v-divider>

                <v-list-item link color="grey lighten-4">
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title to="/about">
                      {{ nextSip["Estado Processo"] }}
                    </v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>

          <v-col>
            <v-alert icon="mdi-database-outline" prominent text type="info">
              FILA DE TRABALHO COM {{ workFlowSize }}.
            </v-alert>
            <v-sheet min-height="70vh" rounded="lg" v-if="switchLogIn">
              <router-view></router-view>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    links: ["Dashboard"],
    switchLogIn: false,
    workFlow: "",
    workFlowSize: 0,
    nextSip: Object,
  }),
  sockets: {
    connect: function () {
      this.$swal("Conectado com Sucesso", "Servidor Localhost:3001", "success");
      console.log("socket connected");
    },
    workFlowSize(data) {
      this.workFlowSize = data;
    },
    nextSip: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    switchLogIn: function (value) {
      if (value == true) {
        console.log("Im LOGIN");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

but not here

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <SipForm/>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
import SipForm from "@/components/SipForm.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    SipForm,
  },
  data: () => ({
    workFlowSize: 0,
  }),
  sockets: {
    connect: function () {
      this.$swal("Conectado com Sucesso", "Servidor Localhost:3001", "success");
      console.log("socket connected");
    },
    workFlowSize(data) {
      this.workFlowSize = data;
    },
    nextSip: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[image: CONSOLE VIEW]

Comment: `nextSip: Object`  don't do this. If you want to initialise `nextSip` as an object, use `nextSip: {}`